# How can I prove that any matrix A can be expressed as the sum of two Hermitian matrices , B and C, in the form A = B + iC?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is in the title really.  Whether or not A must also be Hermitian is not clear to me.  Sorry, I am not very good with proofs of this nature.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are working with $n \times n$ matrices over the complex numbers. Let $A^\ast$ denote the Hermitian adjoint of $A$, i.e. the complex conjugate of the transpose. Then, by definition, $A$ is Hermitian if and only if $A = A^\ast$. Now suppose that $A$ is an arbitrary complex $n \times n$ matrix. Set $B = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^\ast)$ and $C = -\frac{i}{2}(A - A^\ast)$. Then it is easy to check that (i) $B = B^\ast$; (ii) $C = C^\ast$; and (iii) $A = B + iC$.